# React.js: how to set an active flag in one of multiple identical children?

Tags: reactjs, events

I have a parent component with multiple identical children of which only one can be active at a time. The active state is to be set through an internal event on the child itself e.g. a button click, and not by the parent. I want the active state to be unset by a call from a sibling but I cant find a way for siblings to call eachother's methods. Ive tried refs but they are only accessible from the parent and i cant find a way to make a child ref available within itself without maintaining a list of refs on the parent which i dont want as i only need to store the currently active one.

Simple example

e.g.

```
<Parent>
  <Child active={false}/>
  <Child active={false}/>
  <Child active={true}/>
</Parent>
```

where a child is something like

```
export class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super(props);
    state  = {
     active: props.active; 
    }
  } 

  setActive(active) {
    setState ({active : active});
  }

  onclick = () => {
     // get currently active other sibling?
     // call setActive direct on other sibling.
     // e.g. other.setActive(false);

     // set current to active using the same method
     this.setActive(true);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button onclick={this.onclick}/>
      <p>current state={this.state.active ? "active": "inactive"}
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried passing in parent setActiveRef and getActiveRef functions as props to the children to maintain a single shared ref (the active one) and use getActiveRef().current.setActive directly but i cant find a way to access the ref of a child component from within itself to send to the setActiveRef() on the parent in the first place.

any advice much appreciated. thanks

Comment: This is a typical use case for a more generic approach : you could handle your app state using the Context API (https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or a Flux approach (Redux: https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react/ or MobX: https://mobx.js.org/README.html). It would definitely be overkill for this simple use case, but as your app grows keep in mind that it is all about state management and centralization.

Answer (score 2):

In short, this isn't how React is designed - children won't be able to modify each other's state directly.  A simple analogy would be a literal parent and their children.  You want the children to know when it's time to raise their hand, but they don't take directions from each other, only from Mom or Dad.  What you CAN do is tell the kids how to communicate with their parents, and let their parents deal with it.

I'm sure there are better ways, but here is some code:

```
export class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super(props);

        state = {
            activeChild: "Jimmy"
        }   
    };

    // Let the parents listen for requests  
    handleChildRequest (name) => {
        this.setState({activeChild: name});
    };

    render() {          
        <div>
            <Child active={this.state.activeChild === "Jimmy"} name="Jimmy" handleRequest={this.handleChildRequest} />
            <Child active={this.state.activeChild === "Sally"} name="Sally" handleRequest={this.handleChildRequest} />
            <Child active={this.state.activeChild === "Fred"} name="Fred" handleRequest={this.handleChildRequest} />
        </div>
    };  
}

export class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super(props);
    // Lets forget about local state, we don't need it!
  } 

  onclick = () => {
     this.props.handleRequest(this.props.name); 
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button onclick={this.onclick}/>
      <p>current state={this.props.active ? "active": "inactive"}
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer to my own question using component passing (this) references to parent callback. This is not complete code but i illustrates the point. Appears to work fine for my use case (updating realtime map locations) which is more complex than this simplified example.

parent component passes callbacks to children to store ref to active component

```
export class Parent extends React.Component {
  activeChild = undefined;

  setActiveChild = (child) => {
    activeChild = child;
  }

  getActiveChild = () => {
    return activeChild;
  }

  // set up some callback props on each child
  render() {
    return (
      <Parent>
        <Child active={false} setActiveChild={setActiveChild} getActiveChild={getActiveChild}/>
        <Child active={false} setActiveChild={setActiveChild} getActiveChild={getActiveChild}/>
        <Child active={true} setActiveChild={setActiveChild} getActiveChild={getActiveChild}/>
      </Parent>
    )
}
```

each child simply calls back on the parent using prop callbacks and passes itself. this allows the state to be set internally within the component forcing a re-render if values change.

```
export class Child extends React.Component {
  onclick = () => {
     // get currently active other sibling stored in parent
     let active = this.props.getActiveChild();

     // call setActive directly on other sibling.
     active.setActive(false);

     // store currently active child in parent
     this.props.setActiveChild(this);

     // set 'this' component to active using the same method
     this.setActive(true);
  }}
```

criticisms and improvements most welcome.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to do something similar with hooks, and this is what worked for me:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Parent = () => {
  const [activeChild, setActiveChild] = useState(undefined);
  
  return (
    // Now the children have access to the current active child
    // and also the ability to change that

    <Child activeChild={activeChild} setActiveChild={setActiveChild} id={'1'}/>
    <Child activeChild={activeChild} setActiveChild={setActiveChild} id={'2'}/>
  )

export default Parent
```

then inside the Child component...

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
        
const Child = ({activeChild, setActiveChild, id}) => {
  const [activated, setActivated] = useState(false);
    
  useEffect(() => {
    if (activeChild !== id) {
      setActivated(false);
      }
    
    }, [activeChild, chapter]);
  return (
    //on click the component will be able to be activated and set itself as the activated component.
    <div onClick={()=> {      
    setActivated(true);
    setActiveChild(id)
    }} />
    )
        
export default Child
```

The useEffect in the Child will check if its `id` (which is unique to itself) is the id of the `activeChild`. If not, it'll make sure that its local state of `activated` is false.

Once activated though, it'll set its local state of `activated` to true, and set the activeChild's `id` to its own id.

any feedback is welcome!! This made sense in my head.

Answer (score -1):

Let's supposed you have an array of childs components, each one of those child, will have a prop called active, so you could use an state variable to store the array of childs, so when one of the childs gets updated, and cause a rerender of each one of the child components as well.

```
import React from "react";
const Parent = () => {
  const childs = [{ active: false }, { active: false }, { active: false }];

  const [childrens, setChildrens] = React.useState(childs);

  const onOptionSelected = idx => {
    setChildrens(prevOptions =>
      prevOptions.map((opt, id) => {
        opt.active = id === idx;
        return opt;
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {childrens.map((child, id) => {
        return (
          <Child
            key={id}
            id={id}
            active={child.active}
            onOptionSelected={onOptionSelected}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = ({ id, active, onOptionSelected }) => {
  console.log(id)
  const onClick = () => {
    onOptionSelected(id);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={onClick}>set active</button>
      <p>current state={active ? "active" : "inactive"}</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

Comment: This involves maintaining an array of active statuses which is surplus as the parent only needs to know a single active status.